# Ionic2 angular2 load view after subscribe

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm looking to go to the next view in my app after running an http post.

I have 3 service:

1. server service - generic http calls - get, post etc
2. city service - stores a city list data across the app which call service 1 and gets data
3. drill service - drills into the city list displays info about the city once its receives the data from city service

In angular 1 I would pass in a function (callback) that would denote its ok to load the page or do something now we have the data. However I'm a little stuck in version 2 on how to achieve this after a http call.

Server service I use for generic post or get requests:

```
post(data){       
 var postData = 'data='+JSON.stringify(data);

 return this.http.post(this.server, postData, {
  headers: this.headers
 })
 .map(res => res.json());          
}
```

City service that calls the above `post(data)` city service also stores the data which, I re-use across the app:

```
viewCity(send){   
this.server.post(send).subscribe((data) => {        
    this.data.cityData = data.city;
    //ONCE HERE I WANT TO THEN LOAD THIS
    //ANGULAR ONE THE CALLBACK RUN HERE
});
}
```

So when I call `viewCity` from the `drill` service how can I get ionic to change view after the call has finished?

I've tried using a callback but the function passed in is null and doesn't work. Incorrect TypeScript syntax maybe?

EDIT / UPDATE:

So i have managed to make it work but i don't like the solution. Can anyone improve on this:

```
  viewCity(r){    
  this.cityService.getCity(r)
  .subscribe((data) => {  //call the service and return the http object
      this.cityService.data.city = data.city; //set the data back through to the service
      this.nav.push(RestaurantPage); //load the page and access the service in this component 
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to the service to let the page know when the service is done, and push the new page. Please take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4ZegzJ?p=preview).

First, in the page that calls the service, we subscribe to the service like this:

```
  constructor(private nav: NavController, private service: MyService) {         
        // When the service tells us, we're going to redirect
        // the user to the Page1
        this.service.getData.subscribe((receivedData) => {
            this.nav.push(Page1, { data : receivedData });
        });         
    }
```

Please notice that we could also send the information from the service to the next page as a parameter.

Then, in the service, use the `next` method on the observer instance so we can tell all the subscribers (the page that called the service in this case) to execute what's next.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MyService { 

  private getDataObserver: any;
  public getData: any;

  constructor(){
    // Initialize the observer
    this.getDataObserver = null;
    this.getData = Observable.create(observer => {
        this.getDataObserver = observer;
    });
  }

  public getDataFromServer() {
    // Let's pretend this method gets data from the server
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.getDataObserver.next("This is a new message retrieved from the service.");
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
viewCity(r){    
  this.cityService.getCity(r)
  .subscribe((data) => {  //call the service and return the http object
      this.cityService.data.city = data.city; //set the data back through to the service
      this.nav.push(RestaurantPage); //load the page and access the service in this component 
  });
  }
```

I assume the `viewCity(r){...}` method is in one of your pages (because you have access to the NavController instance).

The only thing that I'd change there, is that you're using the same service to get the data (`this.cityService.getCity(r)`), and then to save it there too (`this.cityService.data.city = data.city;`).

So why don't you set the city inside the `cityService.getCity(r)` method from the `cityService`and then you just need to redirect to the `RestaurantPage` when the service is done:

```
viewCity(r){    
  this.cityService.getCity(r).subscribe((data) => {  //call the service and return the http object
      this.nav.push(RestaurantPage); //load the page and access the service in this component 
  });
}
```

Comment: That would work but the getDataFromServer() is then coupled with the observer to go that page everytime it's called. The function is called mulitple times and doesn't always go to that page.

Comment: thanks but getCity(r) essentially runs: this.http.post(this.server, postData, {
  headers: this.headers
 })
 .map(res => res.json())  so it doesn't process the subscribe before. Your change would just get the data but not set it in the service